# I was trying to make it so something would equal something else Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, words

I decided to make a code with a friend and wanted to be able to crack (decode) it with this program. Basically what I want is one word to equal another for example the word "be" would show in the program as the word "ok".

So I have the raw_input to put the words to crack in. Say I put in the sentence "hi friend" how would I get it to come out as for example "dog crazy". Also if I put in "dog crazy" to come out as "hi friend".

Sorry if this is hard to understand but I'm not sure how to explain it to well.

I am using Python 2.7.3. Thanks.

Comment: You can use dictionary `{'hi':'dog', 'friend':'crazy'}` and then replace each word in the input with its value in the dictionary.

Comment: Ok i'll try that right now thanks!  I'll tell you if it works.

Comment: So what I have is as follows

Comment: wordCrack = raw_input("Enter words to crack: ")

Comment: You should edit your question rather than putting the code in comment

Comment: {'hi':'dog', 'friend:'crazy'}

Comment: ok i will but when  i try to put in the words the program quits itself!  ANd also this is my first time using this website so im figuring it out still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on simonzack idea but with some improvements and fixing.

```
mapping = {
    'hi':       'dog',
    'friend':   'crazy',
}

# Add to mapping dog->hi and friend->crazy automatically.
mapping.update({v:k for k, v in mapping.items()})

# Convert using mapping.
print(' '.join([mapping.get(w, w) for w in raw_input().split()]))
```

Verified:

```
% python sol.py 
hello crazy friend
hello friend crazy

% python sol.py
crazy dog
friend hi
```

Comment: ok I copied and pasted exactly but it didn't work... Just a blank line came up.

Comment: What Python version are you using? This code is for Python 2.7.

Comment: I'm using 2.7.3 and copy and pasting it as it is.

Comment: Ok but are you sure the "blank line" that came up is not the raw_input() waiting you type a sentence to convert?

Comment: The program starts when I click run but then the in the python shell it is blank except for the >>>.

Comment: Wait I need to put something for the raw_input() in?  I thought it was just there for no reason!  One sec I'll try.

Comment: So what do I need to type in the raw_input if I put dog lazy will it convert it to hi friend?

Comment: Yes. It will convert it. (answer updated to add this example)

Comment: Do I need quotes or anything? I tried with quotes and without and it didn't work it would just say dog crazy when i add quotes and syntax error without anything!

Comment: No. But if you wish to try, you can replace `raw_input()` by `"crazy dog"` (with the quotes).

Comment: Thanks it worked like that!!  Thanks so much I can get moving on now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

mapping={
    'hi':       'dog',
    'friend':   'crazy',
}

for k,v in list(mapping.items()):
    mapping[v]=k

print(' '.join(map(lambda w: mapping.get(w,w),input().split())))
```

Comment: Tried it and it said: line 11, in <module> print(' '.join(map(lambda w : mapping[w] if w in mapping else w,input().split())))                  File "<string>", line 0                                                         SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Make sure you copy the last bracket